Problem with loading JSON file into IndexedDB through javascript
So I need to load this file into IndexedDB called Admin.json and these are the contents of it:
[
 {"username": "sheilah", "password": "sheilah123"},
 {"username": "joella", "password": "joella123"},
 {"username": "roselin", "password": "roselin123"},
 {"username": "rozalin", "password": "rozalin123"},
 {"username": "melisse", "password": "melisse123"},
 {"username": "berny", "password": "berny123"},
 {"username": "bink", "password": "bink123"},
 {"username": "vaughn", "password": "vaughn123"},
 {"username": "elmira", "password": "elmira123"},
 {"username": "roddie", "password": "roddie123"}
]

So I have written this code for it in my js file:
let db;

function openDatabase() {
  const request = indexedDB.open('HospitalDB', 1); // Open database with version 1

  request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
    db = event.target.result;

    // Create an object store for 'admins' if it doesn't exist
    if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('admins')) {
      const store = db.createObjectStore('admins', {
        keyPath: 'username'
      }); // 'username' as the unique key
      store.createIndex('password', 'password', {
        unique: false
      }); // Create an index on 'password'
    }
    console.log("Database created/updated successfully!");

    // Create an object store for 'patients' if it doesn't exist
    if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('patients')) {
      db.createObjectStore('patients', {
        keyPath: 'id'
      });
    }

    // Create an object store for 'medicines' if it doesn't exist
    if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('medicines')) {
      db.createObjectStore('medicines', {
        keyPath: 'id'
      });
    }
  }

  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    db = event.target.result;
    console.log("Database opened successfully!");

    // Call the function to load and insert the admin data
    loadAndInsertAdminData();
    loadAndInsertPatientData();
    loadAndInsertMedicineData();
  }
  // Function to load and insert the admin data into the IndexedDB

  async function loadAndInsertAdminData() {
    try {
      // Fetch the admin data from the local JSON file
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/files/Admin.json');
      const adminData = await response.json();

      // Insert the admin data into the IndexedDB
      const transaction = db.transaction(['admins'], 'readwrite');
      const store = transaction.objectStore('admins');

      adminData.forEach(admin => {
        const request = store.add(admin);
        request.onsuccess = () => {
          console.log(`Added admin ${admin.username} to the database.`);
        };
        request.onerror = (event) => {
          console.error("Error adding admin:", event.target.error);
        };
      });

      transaction.oncomplete = function() {
        console.log("All admin data added to the database.");
      };

      transaction.onerror = function(event) {
        console.error("Transaction error:", event.target.error);
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching or inserting admin data:", error);
    }
  }

The admin file is loading onto the DB but I'm still getting an error saying "error adding admin" along with the transaction error. I've used similar code for my other 2 json files Medicines.json and Patients.json and those files arent even showing up on the DB when i go to the developer tools from inspect element on my website. I'm getting the same transaction errors and error fetching the file for those files too. For context I'm running the localhost:8000 from my project file directory with the cmd command: python -m http.server 8000 . What's the problem here?

What "transaction error"?

Transaction error: DOMException: The transaction was aborted, so the request cannot be fulfilled.

Let me ask you this... You're using the IndexedDB at the server side or at the client side? If it is in the client side, avoid that at all costs for sensitive data like passwords. Also, place an request.onerror event listener to inspect if the database opening is producing any errors... You're just listening to request.onsuccess...
